# How to get User Identity object from Microsoft Graph with Azure AD B2C

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I have successfully setup an Asp.Net Core web app using Azure AD B2C authentication and Microsoft Graph. I want to return the objectIdentity for the user so I can extract the username from the issuerAssignedId property. However the identities object is null so how can I get this value?

[image]

**Here is my configuration in Startup.**

```
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAdB2C");
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));

services.AddSingleton<IGraphServiceClient>(implementationFactory =>
{
    var clientId = Configuration["MicrosoftGraph:ClientId"];
    var tenantId = Configuration["MicrosoftGraph:TenantId"];
    var secret = Configuration["MicrosoftGraph:ClientSecret"];

    IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(clientId)
        .WithTenantId(tenantId)
        .WithClientSecret(secret)
        .Build();

    ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
    return new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
});
```

**Here is my API settings in Azure AD B2C.**

[image]

**Here is my test user account in Azure AD B2C. Because it is a local account with username I am trying to get the value under the User Principal Name highlighted below.**

[image]

**--- UPDATE ---**

It is definitely a local account I created manually in Azure AD B2C. Here are the settings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Installed Packages

[image]

Comment: Make sure to use the beta endpoint of MS Graph API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you use the Microsoft Graph v1.0 package.

In this case you need to use `$select` to get the `identities` property.

```
var user = await graphClient.Users[oid].Request().Select("identities").GetAsync();
```

Example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request-1) for your reference.

Or you can use Beta version (as @JasSuri suggested) in your project with `Install-Package Microsoft.Graph.Beta -PreRelease` and keep using your original code.

Comment: UPN in azure portal shows a username, so it MUST be a B2C account.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT Thanks for your correction. You are right! Have updated the answer.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT I updated package to Microsoft.Graph.Beta but now I get a reference error in startup with `new GraphServiceClient(authProvider)`. The error is "CS0433 The type 'GraphServiceClient' exists in both 'Microsoft.Graph.Beta, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'Microsoft.Graph". Perhaps it's not compatible with asp.net 5?

Comment: @OjM Please try to uninstall Microsoft.Graph package. In fact Beta version is not recommended in production environment. Did you try `$select` query parameter?

Comment: @AllenWu Updated question showing installed packages and error. I only have the beta version installed but it still gives reference error.

Comment: @OjM Can you show what package is using in your code? For example `using Microsoft.Graph;` or `using Microsoft.Graph.Beta;`.

Comment: @OjM I don't think it's not compatible with asp.net 5. It should be Microsoft.Graph package still remains. Please clean and rebuild. BTW, you can use the first method `$select` because it doesn't require you to use Beta version.

Comment: @AllenWu I can only use `using Microsoft.Graph;` because `using Microsoft.Graph.Beta;` does not exist. This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/use-beta?tabs=CS) says the usage should remain the same.

Comment: @OjM Ah yes. My bad. Did you clean the project and rebuild?

Comment: @AllenWu yep did clean and rebuild but still same error. I ended up removing both packages and it still compiled and ran I assume because I am also referencing `Microsoft.Graph.Auth`. Anyway I used your $select approach and it worked so I'll use that instead. Thanks for your help